# change the background colour of a div based on the text of another using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the background colour of a div based on the text of another div using jQuery and CSS.

my HTML looks like this

```
<div class="livenow-container">                
    <div class="live-content">
    <div class="livenow-artist">Darkpsyde</div>
    <div class="livenow-info">06/05/14 | Transcendent Tuesdays</div>
    <div class="livenow-channelcolour"></div>
    <div class="livenow-channel">Drum and Bass</div>
        <div class="live-thumb"><img src="http://cdn.krisisplay.com/assets/livepic/darkpsydelive.png" class="live"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the background-colour of the "livenow-channelcolour" div to a set colour based on the text in the div directly below it called "livenow-channel"

I had someone help me with something similar before and I tried to change the code to achieve this but its not working. The code I am using is the following however happy to use something completely different if it works.

```
 $(".live-content").each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    var color;
    var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();

    if (content.indexOf("drum and bass") !== -1) {
        color = "#39d52d";
    }
    else if (content.indexOf("house") !== -1) {
        color = "#6dc8bf";
    }

    if (color) {
            $el.closest('div')
            .find('.livenow-channelcolour')
            .css("background-colour", color);
        }
});
```

Any help with this simple but frustrating issue is very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's actually `background-color`, not `background-colour`

Comment: good cathced @adeneo....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried it in fiddle with **backgound** property of css and its working:

```
 $el.closest('div')
        .find('.livenow-channelcolour')
        .css("background", color);
```

Code:

```
$(".live-content").each(function() {

var $el = $(this);
var color;
var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();

if (content.indexOf("drum and bass") != -1) {
    color = "#39d52d";
}
else if (content.indexOf("house") != -1) {
    color = "#6dc8bf";
}

if (color) {
        console.log("if");
        $el.closest('div')
        .find('.livenow-channelcolour')
        .css("background", color);
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sggM/3/)

Comment: Hi, does that jFiddle work for you? I just get Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: as @adeono mention you had spell mistak for ``backgound-color`` property i tested with ``backgound-color`` as well its working with that as well, you had written ``background-colour`` that was the mistak

Comment: Damm the american spellings :P - So I think it might also not be working for me as I see you put text in the channelcolour div, I just want a 5px x 5px square to be coloured with no content. 

I achived this in CSS with the below, leaving it white so there was something there, and just wanted to change the colour. Could this be why when I copy your code above its still not working for me?

.livenow-channelcolour {
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: 5px;
 width: 5px;
 top: 20px;
 left: 86px;
 position: relative;
}

Comment: check the fiddle now actually your css is not right you have fixed height and width use min-height and min-width and it will work with empty content as well

Comment: Awesome, I got it working with this help and changing it from loading at document.ready to window.load, why that change was needed is beyond me.

Comment: I solved that weirdness as well, It was because another piece of javascript updates the text on a setinterval. I moved the code above to run inside that loop and after the text had been updated and it works on document.ready now too. many thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

here is a go at it

http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/uJwE6/

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('.live-content>.livenow-channel').text().toLowerCase(), color;
    switch (text) {
     case 'drum and bass':
        color = '#39d52d';
        break;
     case 'house':
        color = '#6dc8bf';
        break;
     default:
        color = 'transparent';
    }
    $('.live-content>.livenow-channelcolour').css('background', color).text(color);
});
```